# Can't load gesture recogniser on multiple table cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView where I want each cell to respond to a long press gesture.

I attached the gesture recogniser to the prototype cell and connected it to an IBAction on the tableViewController's swift code.

When I run the app, the first cell loads fine, it responds to the long press gesture and no errors.

When I add another item to the table, I get this error:

```
2016-09-09 12:56:52.963 Day Care Register[1044:222155] WARNING: A Gesture
recognizer (<UILongPressGestureRecognizer: 0x7906a220; state = 
Possible; view = <Day_Care_Register.DogTableViewCell 0x799c2c00>; 
target= <(action=dogMarkedForBoarding:, target=
<Day_Care_Register.DogTableViewController 0x7906aa10>)>>) was setup in 
a storyboard/xib to be added to more than one view (->
<Day_Care_Register.DogTableViewCell: 0x7a1bac00; baseClass = 
UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 600 90); clipsToBounds = YES; 
gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x79180200>; layer = <CALayer: 
0x7916cbe0>>) at a time, this was never allowed, and is now enforced. 
Beginning with iOS 9.0 it will be put in the first view it is loaded 
into.
```

OK, so if I understand this right, I can't use the same gesture recogniser over multiple cells?

How do I fix that?

I'm not sure what code you guys would want to see, so if you want to see anything, feel free to ask in a comment and I'll happily provide as soon as I can.

Comment: You have to create UIGestureRecognizer for each UITableViewCell, one gesture recognizer can be assigned only for one view.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that.... I thought i had when i dragged the recogniser onto the cell in the storyboard 

Comment: One way is Drag&Drop UIGestureRecognizer to your prototype cell in Interface Builder and connect it with view which should response for long press. 
Another option is create UILongGestureRecognizer via code and setup it. The best way to do this is awakeFromNib() method.

Comment: Does it matter which view i connect it with?... e.g. can i connect it to a function on the tableViewController even though it's on a tableViewCell?

Comment: @DanielSumara your first suggestion doesn't work, It was what i initially trued, but i retried it to be sure. That method is what's giving me the error

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done this in the past is to create a gesture recognizer for the UITableViewController, assigning it a target selector of the form:

```
func handleLongPress(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
```

When you implement handleLongPress(_:) you can iterate over the visible cells in the table view, testing whether the visible cell's frame contains the point recognizer.locationInView(Self.tableView):

```
func handleLongPress(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
    guard let touchPoint : CGPoint = recognizer.locationInView(self.tableView) else { return }
    let cellInFocus : UITableViewCell? = {
        for cell in self.tableView.visibleCells {
            if cell.frame.containsPoint(touchPoint) {
                 return cell
            }
        }
        return nil
    }()

    guard let _ = cellInFocus else { return }

    // Take desired action with cell...

}
```

Hope that helps!